# How to represent a coffee machine using DFA?

Tags: finite-automata

I want to know how to represent a coffee machine using a Deterministic finite automata?

I've tried a lot to do this job.
I represented each and every processes as a set,by putting one to one correspondence with Natural numbers.
But I still don't know how to represent it using DFA.

Comment: Is this homework? Can you show some of your intermediate results? At what step did you get stuck? What form/notation do you want to produce in your modeling?

Comment: yeah,you said it right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try to imagine the states your automaton can be in. Something like:

```
Off, Ready, Working
```

Afterwards imagine the buttons or inputs you have to perform to switch between these states. Do not forget to define every input on every state. If you leave out several transitions, the automaton is not deterministic therefore is an NFA. Transitions could be:

```
0 for power off/on
1 for start/stop working

Off -0-> Ready
Ready -1-> Working
Ready -0-> Off
Working -1-> Ready  (4 for the actual working process)

Off -1-> Off
Working -0-> Working (nothing happens in this cases)
```

Just connect the states with the given transitions, and voilá!

Comment: So I've to use NFA.http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~mmo/generic/papers/coffee/Coffee-1.html
Attachments area
Preview attachment THE COFFEE MACHINE DESIGN PROBLEM: PART I.html
[HTML]

Comment: Yes, this is an NFA. But stackoverflow is not about solving someone elses homework! ;)

Comment: I want a lil bit of help, that's why I posted a query. If you guys are not interested, then okay. I will do it by myself.

Comment: Ok, i tried to give you a hint about a casual process to designing NFAs. Try to use it!